# Query between two dates exclude weekends and holidays in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Working on a small app which excludes weekends and public holidays from two set dates range. ie if user enters 2019-05-01 and 2019-05-10 it returns the range without the weekends and if there are any public holidays exclude  those from results.

i get the date range with the time per day, working hours from two variables

```
$duration = $endTime  - $startTime;
```

How can i use in_array to 
results returned when i print date between 2019-05-01 and 2019-05-09

```
//date range

Array
(
[2019-05-01] => 09:30:00
[2019-05-02] => 09:30:00
[2019-05-03] => 09:30:00
[2019-05-06] => 09:30:00
[2019-05-07] => 09:30:00
[2019-05-08] => 09:30:00
[2019-05-09] => 09:30:00
)
// public holiadys
Array
(
[0] => 2019-05-08
[1] => 2019-05-09
)

$start = new DateTime('2019-05-01');
$end = new DateTime('2019-05-31');

// getting the day interval https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php
$day = new DateInterval("P1D");

//holidays hardcoded for testing, must create database abd select dates from there
$holidays = array('2016-01-01','2016-03-25');


$days = array();
//hours set to 8 hours a daye
$startTime = new DateTime('08:00:00');
$endTime = new DateTime('17:30:00');
$duration = $startTime->diff($endTime); 

$data = $endTime - $startTime;

foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $day, $end->add($day)) as $day => $k) {
    $day_num = $k->format("N");

    $w = $day_num;
    if($w < 6) { //if its wmore than 5 its weekend 

            $days[$k->format("Y-m-d")] = $duration->format("%H:%I:%S");
    }
}

foreach ($holidays as $value) {
    $value = $value;
}
print_r($days);
print_r($holidays);
```

need to calculate the total time between those dates excluding weekend and public holidays

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**

Comment: note, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say, so I will assume that the weekend part is working.  Just check the `$holidays` array:

```
foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $day, $end->add($day)) as $k) {
    $dnm = $k->format("N");
    $key = $k->format("Y-m-d")

    if($dnm < 6 && !in_array($key, $holidays)) {
        $days[$key] = $duration->format("%H:%I:%S");
    }
}
```

Comment: weekend part was working, tried the in_array function but was getting some error

Comment: prob is i started a while back, when i tried finishing it off i got pulled into another project so i undid the in_array function which was not working and giving errors

Comment: i have a database which i can connect to and pull the set holidays and echo on my page, now when trying to add the date_from and date_to column data to my holiday loop, i get the following error: ** Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given**
`$holidays = array();`
`$holiresuts = "SELECT * FROM holidays where holiday_name IS NOT NULL";`
`$result = mysql_query($holiresuts);`
`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($holiresuts)) {`
`    // array_push($holidays, $row["date_from"]);`
`    $holidays[] = $row[$key];`
`}`

Comment: First off, stop using `mysql_` functions, second `$holiresuts` is a string, you want `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)`